# Error saving service with custom mediator

Tags: wso2-integration-studio, wso2-esb

I've developed custom mediator (Logger) with custom configuration implementation, so I can do something like these:

```
    <inSequence>
        <sequence description="" key="utils.SetDefaultProperties" />
        <log level="full" separator="  |  ">
            <property expression="get-property('RqUID')" name="RqUID" />
            <property expression="get-property('CurOperationName')"
                name="CurOperationName" />
        </log>

        <property name="ErrorCode" value="-100"/>
        <property name="ErrorTxt" value="Ошибочная ошибка"/>

        <croc:Logger xmlns:croc="http://mta.croc.ru/mediation">
            <croc:Source>АСОО</croc:Source>
            <croc:Receiver>КСШ</croc:Receiver>
            <croc:Message>Ошибка обработки</croc:Message>
            <croc:Level>ERROR</croc:Level>
            <croc:SaveMessage>true</croc:SaveMessage>
        </croc:Logger>

        <sequence key="utils.CreateError"/>
        <respond />
    </inSequence>
```

It's work fine, but now I cannot open my proxy with "ESB Editor" in WSO2DevStudio (the latest release) because of error: "Unknown synapse configuration tag: ....".

The question is how can I fix it? Or now I should edit my proxy only with "XML Editor"?

Comment: Dev studio does not know about the new mediator tag(Logger) you have implemented, therefore you have to use an XML Editor(unless you want to improve dev studio support for that mediator).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dev studio does not know about the new mediator tag(Logger) you have implemented, therefore you have to use an XML Editor(unless you want to improve dev studio support for that mediator).

Comment: but old EsbEditor was able to open proxy like these :(

Comment: Alternatively, you can open the file as an XML(XML editor) and save in Dev studio itself.